# Samba. Problem to folder access

Tags: samba

Folder1 has guest access on the local network, Folder2 does not. Folders were created using the same principle, only different locations on the disk and names. What could be the problem?

`sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`

1.

```
[Folder1]
path = /home/user/1
public = yes
guest only = yes
writable = yes
force create mode = 0666
force directory mode = 0777
browseable = yes

sudo mkdir /home/user/1
sudo chmod -R ugo+w /home/user/1
sudo systemctl restart smbd
```

2. 

```
[Folder2]
path = /home/user/2
public = yes
guest only = yes
writable = yes
force create mode = 0666
force directory mode = 0777
browseable = yes

sudo mkdir /home/user/2
sudo chmod -R ugo+w /home/user/2
sudo systemctl restart smbd
```

**UPDATE**

```
> ls -ld /home/?
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Mar 15  2024 /home/1
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Mar 15  2024 /home/2

> ls -l /home/?
>/home/1:
total 0
>/home/2:
total 0
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output `ls -ld /home/user/?`

Comment: @Soren A
Post updated